# Install theme for pinax

Tags: django, pinax

I want to replace the default theme of Pinax with this theme: https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap But I'm not sure i understand the Quick Start instruction. Could you please give me some hint?

```
    Include "pinax-theme-bootstrap" in your requirements file and "pinax_theme_bootstrap" in your INSTALLED APPS.
```

What is the requirements file here?

```
    Make sure both template loaders and staticfiles finders includes app directories.
```

I don't understand what they mean. I see STATICFILES_DIRS and TEMPLATE_LOADERS in file settings.py,they mean that I have to put the pinax_theme_bootstrap directory inside apps folder and included links to this directory. Like this:

```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
          os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "media"),
          os.path.join(PINAX_ROOT, "media", PINAX_THEME),
          os.path.join(PINAX_ROOT, "apps", pinax-theme-bootstrap),
                       ]
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
          "django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source",
          "django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source",
          "apps.pinax-theme-bootstrap",
                       ]


    Site name comes from Sites fixture.
```

I totally don't understand what they mean.

```
    Your "site_base.html" should extend "theme_base.html" and should provide "footer" and "nav" blocks (the latter should just be a ul of li of a links).
```

So I have to put the extends "theme_base.html" inside "site_base.html". And should include both "footer" and "nav" blocks inside "site_base.html" if it didn't have before?

```
    Your pages should have blocks "head_title" and "body" and should extend "site_base.html".
```

So in any pages I want to use this theme, I have to have blocks "head_title" and "body" and should extend "site_base.html". If I have a "base.html" that has already extends "site_base.html", do I have to extends in one more time?

```
    The url name "home" should be defined as the homepage.
```

Not sure.

Please give me some suggestions, thanks!

Comment: I have already installed it using setup.py install command.

Answer (score 2):

I know. Pinax's documentation can drive one crazy... I guess, let's be grateful anyway.

First of all, create `templates/site_base.html`. Example:

```
{% extends "theme_bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block nav %}
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
</ul>

{% endblock %}
{%  block footer %}

        <div class="container">
            <hr>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Myself, 2014</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Then...

> The url name "home" should be defined as the homepage.

This just means that in `urls.py` your home page should be labeled with `name='home'`. For example,

```
url(r'^$', 'app.views.index', name='home'),
```

Otherwise you will get errors such as

```
NoReverseMatch at /account/signup/

Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

In fact, `base.html` has the following line:

```
{% block site_brand %}<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url "home" %}">{{ SITE_NAME }}</a>{% endblock %}
```

How do you think it is going to resolve `url "home"` if you haven't labeled any of your urls as `home`?

This also answers the question about the site name. You have to install Django sites, then `SITE_NAME` will be defined.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the requirements file here?

It is an optional best practice. If you want to know more, here is an article i wrote some time ago: http://dev.chocolatpistache.com/blog/2009/11/04/pinax-virtualenv-setuptools-pip-easy_install-and-requirementstxt/

> Make sure both template loaders and staticfiles finders includes app directories. I don't understand what they mean. I see STATICFILES_DIRS and TEMPLATE_LOADERS in file settings.py

Your TEMPLATE_LOADERS has "django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source". This is the "app loader for templates". You need to check STATICFILES_FINDERS. Those settings should be on by default anyway.

Adding "apps.pinax-theme-bootstrap" to TEMPLATE_LOADERS is plain wrong. It should break your site at some point.

> So I have to put the extends "theme_base.html" inside "site_base.html". And should include both "footer" and "nav" blocks inside "site_base.html" if it didn't have before?

Just copy theme_base.html in yourproject/templates/site_base.html That will make it easier for you.

Links about template inheritance:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#tags (section about "block and extends"
http://dev.chocolatpistache.com/blog/2009/07/15/template-inheritance-explained/

> So in any pages I want to use this theme, I have to have blocks "head_title" and "body" and should extend "site_base.html". If I have a "base.html" that has already extends "site_base.html", do I have to extends in one more time?

Your template "article_detail.html" would be like:

```
  {% extends 'site_base.html' %}{# this is your copy of theme_base.html #}

  {% block head_title %}{{ article.title }}{% endblock %}

  {% block body %}
  <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ article.body }}</p>
  {% endblock %}
```

My recommendation: install Pinax and use it's starter project which has pinax-theme-bootstrap by default (and also many things most project needs by default).

Patience and perseverance my friend, it's a long way to the top if you wanna rock'n'roll :)